# Enable TagHelper Intellisense support in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How do I enable Tag Helpers with Intellisense support in a blank ASP.NET Core RC2 application in Visual Studio 2015, as I'd to do this in RC1 which is pretty known to me.

Comment: Almost same as before. Read the RC2 announcements on GitHub (which are also linked from the Release notes)!!! https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/103

Answer (score 3):

To add Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core RC2 project, add _ViewImports file at the root of the Views Folder and add

`@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

In project.json file, add the following dependencies and tools:

```
{
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "type": "build"
}
 },

 "tools": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
}
},
}
```

**You may have to restart your VS to get Intellisense.**

Comment: Thanks man, I've searched days for this. Even in the default .net core template the Taghelpers ain't working!

Comment: Is the "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50" required under the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" in the "tools" section? Can I remove it?

Comment: I did not try it. I'll dig into that what really this `imports` means. You try and let us know.

Comment: OMG i been at it for 3 days and for the life of me i did not understand why one project uses anchor helper and the other not, if i could give you more then one upvote i would have.